# How can I verify is Email Address available or not in yahoo, google and some other accounts?

Tags: c#

I am Implementing  Contact_us page in my Asp.net.in Email field when we enter the Email Address  it should verify the  is email address available or not in Gmail or Yahoo or Microsoft and some other Accounts without send any verification email. will it possible? can any one please guide me.

Comment: all you can do is verify its in the right format, and exclude certain words like yahoo, gmail ,outlook, etc

Comment: Were there such a way, it'd be abused as it's (moderately) valuable information as to what email addresses are valid/active. This info is not (and should not) be accessible

Comment: Why would you want to know if the address was available?

Comment: There are 2 ways for doing this 
1) use online service for this like https://www.email-validator.net/email-address-online-verification-api.html
2) you can use this library for this purpose https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what *O-Auth authentication* has to do with checking whether the provided email address does exists or not. Only way to validate that the email-id does exists is by sending a test email .... that's it.